# Just upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04 LTS and now I can't install anything at all

Tags: apt, upgrade, python, 20.04, dependencies

I just upgraded my ubuntu VM following the Sotfware Upgrade recommendations:

```
root@ubuntu:/# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

I am currently learning python and other skills using this machine. This upgrade removed some applications that I need including IDLE3 (python interpreter). When I try to install it I get this message:

```
root@ubuntu:/# apt-get install -f idle3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 idle3 : Depends: idle (>= 3.6.7-1~18.04) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Is there a way I can get this solved without having to install a new VM?

Comment: Did you try 'sudo apt install idle', because 'idle' is the actual package name as in synaptic package manager.

Comment: Yes I did, then I get a message about another dependency that is not going to be installed and I try to install it manually just like idle and then it comes to a point where the python3.6-tk packets cannot be installed at all because there are no candidates for it. I just installed another version of ubuntu for now

Comment: Could you show us the output of ```cat /etc/apt/sources.list```. You may remove the # comments from it.